# Mapping the key value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodes

I have array of object. where i have to loop and get information of text and create key value pair >i tried below code some how its getting added as header but value is not populating.I need header like note1... to note25..

Sample response ::

```
registrationD:{
 notes: [
        {
          id: "13,
          text: "",
          lastModified: "20Z",
        },
        {
          id: "4d4",
          text: "",
          lastModified: "2022-08-25T09:14:20Z",
        },
        {
          id: "89",
          text: "",
          lastModified: "2022-08-:20Z",
        },
      ],
}
`
```

```
for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      this.notesColumns.push({
        field: registrationD.notes[ i ]?.text ,
        header: `note${
          i + 1
        }`
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I put in the response provided in the question within an object.

```js
const obj = {registrationD:{
 notes: [
        {
          id: "13",
          text: "",
          lastModified: "20Z",
        },
        {
          id: "4d4",
          text: "",
          lastModified: "2022-08-25T09:14:20Z",
        },
        {
          id: "89",
          text: "",
          lastModified: "2022-08-:20Z",
        },
      ],
}}
```

Make sure `notesColumns` is defined as an array. If you are only using it in the method, better to use const/let, and then return it to the caller.

```
this.notesColumns = [];
```

or

```
const notesColumns = [];
```

Then you can run your code as:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      this.notesColumns.push({
        field: obj.registrationD.notes[i]?.text ,
        header: `note${
          i + 1
        }`
      });
}
```

(use only `notesColumns` without `this` if using const)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for quick response .I tried multiple things ,STill vlaues are not geting populate .Looks like Im missing something here

```

Comment: for ( let i=0 ; i< 25; i++) {

          Obj.registrationDe?.notes?.forEach((s) => {
            const text = s.text ? s.text : '';
            this.noteColumns.push({
              field: `${text}`,
              header: `note${
                i + 1
              }`
            });
            console.log(`${text}`);


          });
        }
this.finalColumns = this.finalColumns.concat(this.noteColumns)

Comment: values are printing but not displaying in csv:(

Comment: Can you post code for how you are converting these values to a CSV format? Might be that it's a problem on that end.